# Problem getting 3D Asymptote to Work on Mac

Tags: mac, asymptote

I've been trying to get [`asymptote`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/asymptote) to work on my MacBook Pro running Yosemite. I downloaded `asymptote` onto the desktop and I tried to install it. I now have a "usr" folder on my desktop (is there a better way to do this? Where is it common to put an asy folder? It seems like there is very little documentation for installing asy on OS X). I created a `config.asy` file (inside the usr file on my desktop) and wrote inside it,

```
import settings;
outformat="pdf";
batchView=false;
pdfviewer="/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/skim";
gs="gs";
```

I created a file `test.txt` with the code

```
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);
size(5cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);
draw(unit box);
```

Then I ran the following in the command prompt:

```
laptop-17364637:usr nphirning$ asy -V test.txt
laptop-17364637:usr nphirning$ 2015-05-09 15:05:45.271 skim[16549:1853625]         
Unsupported: Unsupported Annotation Type
```

It works if I don't import three, but what's the problem with 3D graphics? Any help with the best way to set up `asymptote` would also be great.

Comment: There's a world of pain in trying to install it like that.  For OSX you want to install [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/), which includes Asymptote and everything else it needs.  Install the whole thing - all 2G bytes of it - it's worth it.

Comment: Does MacTex include asymptote? If so where does it usually install? I think I've already installed the MacTex fully.

Comment: I've never tried to install Asymptote on Yosemite, but on earlier versions of the operating system, I've found that the best thing to do is just to do a full installation of the latest version of MacTeX. After that, at least for me, Asymptote "just works." A `config.asy` file can be created if you can figure out where to put it, but it's optional.

Comment: The MacTeX installer puts all the executables in `/usr/texbin/` -- but you don;t really need to worry about that.  Just do a full install and it will create all the paths and links you need.

Comment: One more random note: Asymptote files should generally end in `.asy`, not `.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Converting the comments to an answer*]

On a Mac running OSX it's really not a good idea to try to install Asymptote or any other parts of the TeX ecosystem on their own.  It's much better to install the full [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/) distribution.  Just do a full install, and it will install Asymptote and every thing else it needs.

The executables will go into `/usr/texbin` (which is actually a link to `/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin`) but the installer will create this for you automatically (if necessary), and add it to your `$PATH`.

The only drawback is that the full MacTeX distribution is about 2G bytes in size. (But it's worth it).

After you have completed the install, create your Asymptote file with a `.asy` extension in your favourite editor and compile it from the command line with the command `asy`.

- Use `asy -h` or `texdoc asy` for a summary of the options.
- `texdoc asymptote` will open the user guide.

If you use `texmaker` as your editor, it has a menu options for compiling Asymptote source that should "just work" once you have installed a full MacTeX system.